# If 42000 Starlink satellites interfere with telescope observations from Earth would someone observing from another solar system detect them too?

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, artificial-satellite

SpaceX's Starlink constellation could place up to 42000 satellites around the Earth. Would aliens with their own telescopes notice them? They would be about 150 km apart and could reflect light of this wavelength produced by the Sun's corona. Waves bouncing off the ionosphere could perhaps form a detectable diffraction pattern.

Comment: The Earth itself would be way easier (but still very difficult) to detect.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "distant planet"  Do you mean like "Mars" or do you mean a planet around a different star.

Comment: @Greg Miller The satellites would be about 10km apart and the Sun's corona produces these wavelengths which can bounce off the satellites.

Comment: @James K I have edited the question and it's body to clarify that I mean another solar system and 10 km wavelength light waves.

Comment: It would take millions of satellites to cover the Earth with 10km gaps.  I don't really get the connection to ultralong wavelength radio waves, or why you think a space network of satellites would reflect ultralong wavelength radiowaves.

Comment: @James K.  I have got the satellite separation wrong.Should be around 150 km.  The satellites I was thinking could diffract waves bouncing off the ionosphere (which 10km waves are known to do) and someone in another solar system might detect the diffraction pattern.Diffraction patterns are strong when slit width is about the same as wavelength. But would the signal be intense enough to detect?

Comment: Utterly undetectable. Even assuming millions of satellites, from a nearby solar system the separation of the Earth and the sun would be less than an arcsecond.  One would need a colossal interferometer to even separate the Earth from the sun.  And then the sun would be so much brighter than the reflection from the Earth. Of course you can say "alien technology" and who knows what those colourful characters can build... but no.  Starlink satellites would not be easily detected from an exoplanet

Comment: If I hold a dime in front of your eye, you won't be able to see anything but the dime.  The dime is still invisibly small from a mile away, though.

Comment: @James K   Alien technology  might involve a gravitational lensing black hole that can make photons converge onto a smaller interferometer!

Comment: Yes, that's why this question is unanswerable! To write an answer we would first need to discover aliens.

Answer (score 3):

Not in any way that is special to the Starlink satellites. Many satellites can interfere with earth-based astronomy because they are very close to the earth. A reflection off a satellite that is a few hundred miles away can be brighter than a star that is a few tens of trillions of miles away. But, from a different star, both our sun and the satellites are a few tens of trillions of miles away, and the satellites' reflected light is negligible.

Of course, it is possible to imagine faraway supertelescopes that could detect human artifacts. But such a telescope could also detect the ISS and Iridium flares, among many other things. The Starlink satellites' nuisance effect for earthly astronomers doesn't really make them easier to detect from Alpha Centauri.